# Reshape table created by factor in R

Tags: r, dplyr, xlconnect

I have created a factor using dplyr, and then, rearanged many variables using this factor. 
I'm trying to export to a excel file, but XLConnect is does not recognize factor as a column.

How can I solve this?

Here the code:

**Difining factor:**

```
PorIdade <- dplyr::mutate(diagnostica,
                idade_factor = factor(diagnostica$idadegrupo, 
                                    levels = c(1, 2, 3), 
                                    labels = paste(c("60-69", "70-79", "80 e mais"))),
                idade_character = paste(diagnostica$idadegrupo, "Idade") )
```

**Creating Some tables**

```
sex <- with(PorIdade, table(diagnostica$sexo ,             idade_factor))
cor <- with(PorIdade, table(diagnostica$cor ,              idade_factor))
```

i got this on console:

[image]

**Using XLConnect**

```
Wb <- loadWorkbook("results.xlsx", create=TRUE)
createSheet( Wb,"newSheet")

writeWorksheet(object=Wb, data=sex, rownames=NULL, header=TRUE, sheet="newSheet")
  appendWorksheet(object=Wb, data=cor, rownames=NULL, header=TRUE, sheet="newSheet")
saveWorkbook(Wb,file="resuts.xlsx")
```

Now is what i want to solve. 
With this code, i can get this result in Excel:

```
Var1    |idade_factor   |Freq
Homem   |60-69          |34
Mulher  |60-69          |42
Homem   |70-79          |31
Mulher  |70-79          |26
Homem   |80 e mais      |8
Mulher  |80 e mais      |9
Var1    |idade_factor   |Freq
Amarela |60-69          |7
Branca  |60-69          |53
Negra   |60-69          |12
Parda   |60-69          |4
Amarela |70-79          |1
Branca  |70-79          |34
Negra   |70-79          |16
Parda   |70-79          |6
Amarela |80 e mais      |1
Branca  |80 e mais      |7
Negra   |80 e mais      |5
Parda   |80 e mais      |4
```

I would love to have some resuld like this:

```
            60-69|  70-79  | 80 e mais
Homem  |    34   |  31     | 8
Mulher |    42   |  26     | 9

Amarela|    7    |  1      | 1
Branca |    53   |  34     | 7
Negra  |    12   |  16     | 5
Parda  |    4    |  6      | 4
```

I know that i can read in correct way on R, but i want to improve the .xlsx output, since i'll use much more variables

Comment: What package (if any) is the diagnostica data set in?Or is it the same as the table you read in from Excel? Also, are there multiple tables within your Excel file? Do you want those to be different objects in your output or should everything be part of the same data frame?

Comment: For sure. Sorry. 
"diagnostica" is a "tbl_df" type. from a excel with 3 different sheets. From str i get: `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  48 variables:`

Variables are sorted in `data`, `text` and `numeric`

Comment: Without seeing a sample of the diagnostica data, it's really hard to make any suggestions. However, I'd probably use `tidyr::spread()` to reshape your data frames, rather than `table()`.